# JPA hibernate persistence pb

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two server applications with the same `database`.

I created the persistence for each application. They connect to the same `database`.

The problem is that the **application 1** cannot see the data that's committed by **application 2** sometimes (in the query (`em.createQuery`)).

I found a solution for this problem by closing and reopening the `EntityManager` before creating the query.

Is there an easier solution in JPA?

Comment: Do you use a second-level cache or a query cache in application 1?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a second-level cache enabled and one em can't see the cached data of the second em

**solutions:**

1. deactivate the second-level cache
2. use a network cache with replication
3. use a single `EJB-application` as db-layer and use Beans to communicate with your DB